# ruby on rails gitorious setup on ubuntu

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, git

I've been trying to install gitorious for a while now which required ruby and rails etc. I've finally got rails pages serving but can't finish the installation of gitorious because the gem version is too new.

The error logs say

> please run 'rake ultrasphinx:configure'

and that gives

```
rake ultrasphinx:configure
(in /var/www/apps/gitorious)
rake aborted!
uninitialized constant ActiveSupport::Dependencies::Mutex
/var/www/apps/gitorious/Rakefile:10:in `require'
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

From searching google this is because of the wrong gem version. Can't find a way to down grade it.

Apparently `sudo gem update --system 1.4.2` should do the trick but Ubuntu 10.10 does not like this.

> ERROR:  While executing gem ... (RuntimeError)
>           gem update --system is disabled on Debian, because it will overwrite the content of the rubygems Debian package, and might break your Debian system in subtle ways. The Debian-supported way to update rubygems is through apt-get, using Debian official repositories.
>       If you really know what you are doing, you can still update rubygems by setting the REALLY_GEM_UPDATE_SYSTEM environment variable, but please remember that this is completely unsupported by Debian.

So I added `export REALLY_GEM_UPDATE_SYSTEM=1` to .bashrc and reloaded it with . ~/.bashrc and still the same. I've tried various forms of setting this environmental variable with no luck.

I've also been told on #gitorious irc channel to add the file config/initializers/rubygems.rb with the line `require "thread"` to it. This has done nothing.

EDIT:
Just found another way which was `rvm install rubygems 1.4.2`

and it gave:

```
Removing old Rubygems files...
Installing rubygems dedicated to ruby-1.8.7-p334...
Retrieving rubygems-1.4.2
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100  288k  100  288k    0     0   282k      0  0:00:01  0:00:01 --:--:--  414k
Extracting rubygems-1.4.2 ...
Installing rubygems for /home/ubuntu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p334/bin/ruby
ERROR: Error running 'GEM_PATH="/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p334:/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p334@global:/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p334@global" GEM_HOME="/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p334" "/home/ubuntu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p334/bin/ruby" "/home/ubuntu/.rvm/src/rubygems-1.4.2/setup.rb"', please read /home/ubuntu/.rvm/log/ruby-1.8.7-p334/rubygems.install.log
WARN: Installation of rubygems did not complete successfully.
```

TL;DR
Please tell me how to downgrade rubygems on ubuntu 10.10 or upgrade gitorious to work with 1.6.2 gems.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

nevermind... even though it says it failed, `rvm install rubygems 1.4.2` has worked

Answer (score 1):

I've had the same problem. Now there are two additional installation guides on top of the installation guide page on gitorious:

[Ubuntu 10.04](http://www.silly-science.co.uk/2010/12/12/installing-gitorious-on-ubuntu-10-04-howto/)

[Ubuntu 11.04](http://coding-journal.com/installing-gitorious-on-ubuntu-11-04/)

That solved this and other problems in the installation process for me, hopefully this helps others too.

Answer (score 0):

I think the proper way of doing it is:

```
rvm rubygems 1.4.2
```

That tells rvm to change the version of rubygems, instead of trying to install one.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try the [BitNami installer for Gitorious](http://bitnami.org/stack/gitorious). It is self-contained and independent of your system. It installs everything that you need to run Gitorious in your own machine.